# Will there be a Log4J 2.0 release (and if so, when)?

Tags: logging, log4j

It seems like v2 of Log4j has been in development for literally years.  The [Apache Log4J site](http://logging.apache.org/) no longer lists a roadmap, the dev mailing list seems almost entirely about 1.2 (which is appreciated!), use of v1.3 is discouraged, and the 2.0 branch is listed as "experimental".  What's a believer to believe?

Comment: Log4J is too intrusive. Consider a less intrusive logging library such as [MentaLog](http://mentalog.soliveirajr.com) which also produces ZERO garbage when logging.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Log4j development has for all practical purposed stalled. Consider switching to logback, log4j's successor. Logback is conceptually similar to log4j and if you like log4j, you should like logback even better. It has many nice features and is well-documented.

Disclosure: I am the founder of both log4j and logback projects.

Comment: Ceki, you should really declare your interest before making such recommendations.

Comment: skaffman, I added a disclosure taking your comment into consideration. I believe that my statement about log4j development being stalled is factual and a mere observation of reality. Wouldn't you concur?

Comment: As founder, I'd be really curious to hear your opinion/explanation as why it failed...

Comment: Ceki, perhaps you should add a line or two about why you forked log4j?

Comment: @Ceki I just looked at log4j 2.0 and it seems like its now being actively developed and touted as a replacement for logback. Will the real (best) logging framework please standup!

Comment: @Adam Notwithstanding its name, log4j 2.0 is very different than log4j 1.x. I think that log4j 2.0 will encourage developers to move to logback which imho is the true and only successor to log4j 1.x.

Comment: @Ceki "imho the true and only successor".  It is perfectly fine to create a new project that _you_ intend to succeede log4j, but log4j is a community effort (which you were involved in) and it is only the whole community that can decide this.  I think you either should let logback stand on its own as the best backed for slf4j - which it is good enough to do - or at least include a brief explanation when promoting logback as a successor to log4j why you did not just create log4j 2.0 instead.  All these political agendas get in the way...

Answer (score 2):

logback is log4j's succesor

Comment: logback is a fork of log4j 1.3.  The log4j folks talk about a version 2.0 with a lot of new ideas - it seems that new development primarily happen in logback

Comment: From logback's home page: "Logback is intended as a successor to the popular log4j project. It was designed by Ceki Gülcü, the founder of log4j."

Comment: @Olivier,  I do not believe the log4j development team have expressed this explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I was on the log4j lists earlier this year.  Last I knew they were busy back-porting features in 1.3 to the 1.2.15 branch.  During couple months I was on there I never heard anything about log4j v 2 so I assume that it's pretty much abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Well then I guess you already answered your own question, the devs have obviously stopped focusing on 2.0 builds a long time ago and have instead decided to continue the 1.x codebase.

And if you are on their mailing list, then ask them, the source of the issue.

Comment: They're continuing 1.2 maintainence/bugfixes. 1.3 was started, but it was decided that many of the changes in 1.3 were too drastic to be considered for a 1.x release, and would instead be put in 2.0 or backported to 1.2 and offered as extensions. I haven't really heard anything about 2.0 in a while.